# Override All Header and Footer Styles for All Chapter Title and Content Pages?

Tags: header-footer, memoir, chapters, xpatch, page

<sup>**Closely Related:**

- [Create Separate Footer and Header for Chapter Title and Content Pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413598/create-separate-footer-and-header-for-chapter-title-and-content-pages)</sup>

## 1. Use Case - Decoupling Layout from Content:

Content Authors will provide TeX content via a web portal, which will likely include `\chapter{Chapter Title}` and most probably footnote, math, image, and other TeX syntax.

However - it is often the case that the default `chapter title page` and `chapter content page` styles could be wrongfully specified by these authors, or ***get corrupted*** through other imports (`\input`, `\include`, `\usepackage`, etc.)

**Clarification:** A `Chapter Title Page` is the first page of a chapter. `Chapter Content Pages` are the remaining content pages of the chapter. This has nothing to do with a Table of Contents, but should not effect the ToC.

---

## 2. Question:

With the Memoir, Book, or other document classes, is it possible to do what the related question is doing with the `\xpatchcmd`?

Is it possible to define and apply custom classes, only once, to affect all `Chapter Title Pages` and `Chapter Content Pages`, throughout an entire document, without all of the code repetition as seen in similar questions?

**Goals:**

1. To be able to define headers and footers for Chapter Title Pages and Chapter Content Pages separately, (which the current answer is limited from doing).
2. To eventually have separate custom styles for each Part in a book, (without worrying about default styles being corrupted.
3. Less code repetition.
4. Could override unwelcome customizations in imported documents.
5. To blacklist `\xpatchcmd` and any other patch commands from being used.

---

## 3. Code Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{chapter}
    \makeheadrule{chapter}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
    \makefootrule{chapter}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
    \makeoddhead {chapter}{left header}{odd header}{right header}
    \makeoddfoot {chapter}{left footer}{odd footer}{right footer}
    % ***** Added in Even Page Headers and Footers to show on Chapter Content Pages
    \makeevenhead {chapter}{left header}{even header}{right header}
    \makeevenfoot {chapter}{left footer}{even footer}{right footer}


    \makepagestyle{alternate}
    \makeheadrule{alternate}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
    \makefootrule{alternate}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
    \makeoddhead {alternate}{left header}{alternate odd header}{right header}
    \makeoddfoot {alternate}{left footer}{alternate odd footer}{right footer}
    \makeevenhead {alternate}{left header}{alternate even header}{right header}
    \makeevenfoot {alternate}{left footer}{alternate even footer}{right footer}


\begin{document}

    % ***** What Memoir Code could go here, to override all
    % ***** chapter title and content pagestyles?
    % ***** How to specify all chapter Title and Content Pages
    % ***** ... without having to provide an actual chapter.
    % ***** ... \xpatch can do this, but does Memoir have a way?

    \chapter{Non-Styled Chapter}
    \chapterprecis{Ideally the only code would be the \\ include command.  Authors will only have TeX code specific to their own content - with no knowledge of current styles, etc.  There would be no "\\ pagestyle" commands in these \\ include -ed files.  Here, chapter content pages have no custom headers and footers.  }
    % \include("./Content/MyContent.text")
    \sloppy\lipsum

    \chapter{Test Chapter With required \\ pagestyle command}
        \chapterprecis{Required to use inner Styling to get Headers and Footers.}
        % **** Chapter Content Pages Need this \pagestyle command?
        \pagestyle{chapter}
        \sloppy\lipsum

    % ***** Every \chapter tag would reqire \chapterstyle, etc.
    % ***** Chapter Content will actually be pulled in via \include.
    \chapterstyle{bianchi}
    \chapter{Testing Bianchi Chapter Style}
        \chapterprecis{Built in Chapter Styles have no impact on headers and footers.%
        Have to resort to including \\ pagestyle in order to override possible%
        corruption of default \\ pagestyle\{chapter\} }

        \pagestyle{alternate}
        \sloppy\lipsum

    % ***** Bianchi Chapter Test 2, Without Style Tags
    \chapter{Non-Styled Chapter}
        \chapterprecis{Chapter Without Any Style Commands. Inherits globally altered changes.  This is what I am hoping to avoid.}
        \sloppy\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show at all that you are trying to do different things for the first pages of different kinds of chapters. How are people supposed to guess that? Werner's crystal ball is evidently in excellent shape, but we don't all have crystals of similarly quality.

Comment: `xpatch` is not replacing anything in the whole body. It changes the definition of a macro. The macro can be used multiple times.

Comment: it isn't very clear what problem you are trying to solve. It seems you have authors writing separate chapters to be included into a main document. They can only reference page styles that have been defined, so it is up to you to just provide the needed styles. (I deleted comments on the earlier version)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "corruption by all imports" as I said I would only expect a chapter that is imported to use page styles defined in the document preamble, and if you control the document preamble then there should be no issue.

Comment: do you just mean that you do not want to allow `\chapterstyle{bianchi}` if so `\renewcommand\chapterstyle[1]{}` would disable this command, but I can not really guess. Ultimately it is a social issue that you need to control by author guidelines not by technology, any latex input can redefine _any_ part of latex.

Comment: but that is the normal situation, the page styles are defined in the class and used in the body. Sorry I give up I can not guess what the problem is that you are trying to solve or what answer you expect. Hopefully the existing answer helps in some way.

Comment: as I say I can not guess what the issue is (and the reference to xpatchcmd confuses it even more as I said at the beginning:-) but it might just be me, I didn't say it was a bad question or that you do not have a real issue, simply that I tried and failed to understand the question so i give up, however there are lots more people on the site who could answer.

Comment: I've deleted my comments which applied to a much earlier version. I don't understand what you are trying to do and I don't understand your terminology. For example, what do you mean by a 'Content Page' and what by a 'Chapter Title Page'. Contents listings are typically typeset as chapters in `book`-like classes, so the first page of them is the first page of a chapter. On the other hand, pages with content but without chapter titles on them are formatted differently from pages with chapter titles on them by default.

Comment: It is impossible to blacklist all possible patch commands because new ones can be defined. The most you can do is redefine a target list of commands so they give errors or do nothing. But I don't see the point. People can still redefine anything they like. And the 'corruption' issue makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: There is no consensus 'no' because nobody understands your question. As I understand it, Werner's solution fails because you say you can't distinguish the styles applied to the first pages of chapters and other pages in those chapters. **But those styles are different by default.** You don't have to do anything to distinguish them.

Comment: @cfr - I am having a hard time understanding too.  I feel that this is a very common layout pattern in publishing, to customize the styles of chapter title pages, and chapter content pages separately from each other.  And, code repetition seems an avoided anti-pattern.  Further, using the `\xpatchcmd` seems to be a very, very, non-standard technique to do this. This leads me to believe that there is another best practice. I have updated the question to clarify the terminology differences you pointed out. Perhaps someone familiar with these patterns can help me rephrase the question.

Comment: Of course it is a standard pattern. Standard in LaTeX classes and packages, standard in publishing .... You would have to go out of your way to produce a document using LaTeX which had chapters and didn't have this pattern. Of course. That's why your question makes no sense to me: you seem to be saying that something we've said or something Werner said or something Memoir does excludes use of this pattern. But, of course, it doesn't. On the contrary, everything we've said, everything Memoir does presumes it. But please stop calling them 'content pages'.

Comment: No idea what repetition you're referring to. No idea what corruption you're referring to. No idea at all why you'd think xpatch is required for this. Perhaps somebody else will understand - maybe somebody familiar with the context your terminology makes sense in. I'm only really familiar with LaTeX, so it just confuses me, but other people have led less sheltered lives.

Answer (score 6):

`\xpatchcmd` (from [`xpatch`](//ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)) has the same format/interface than its counterpart `\patchcmd` (from [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

```
\xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

`\xpatchcmd` searches for `<search>` in `<cmd>` and replaces it with `<replace>`. If this search-and-replace is successful, it executes `<success>`, otherwise it executes `<failure>`. In your code example (after removing the comments),

```
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{chapter}}{}{}{}
```

searches for `\thispagestyle{chapter}` inside `\chapter` and replaces it with nothing. The `<success>` and `<failure>` branches are also left blank for brevity. Effectively, the above command removes `\thispagestyle{chapter}` from `\chapter`.

Secondly, you're confusing `\chapterstyle` with `\pagestyle`. They're different. A *chapter* style (defined using `\makechapterstyle`) is used with a call to `\chapterstyle` and defines the way the chapter heading/title is set, not the chapter page header/footer. The latter is called a *page* style and is created using `\makepagestyle` and used/set via `\thispagestyle` (for the current page only) or `\pagestyle` (for pages form the current on onward).

Here is a demonstration of the `veelo` *chapter* style, for example:

[image]

```
% ...
\setcounter{chapter}{3}% Just for this example
\chapterstyle{veelo}
\chapter{Demonstration of the veelo \\ chapter style}
\sloppy\lipsum
%...
```

The way the heading - `Chapter 4` - and title - `Demonstration of the veelo \\ chapter style` - is set has been changed, but the *page* style is still `chapter`.

Here is a demonstration of applying the `ChapterPage` *page* style to the first pages of a `\chapter` under the `madsen` *chapter* style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\makepagestyle{ChapterPage}
\makeheadrule{ChapterPage}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{ChapterPage}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeoddhead {ChapterPage}{left header}{centre header}{right header}
\makeoddfoot {ChapterPage}{left footer}{centre header}{right header}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\copypagestyle{chapter}{ChapterPage}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}% Just for this example
\chapterstyle{madsen}
\chapter{Demonstration of the madsen \\ chapter style}
\sloppy\lipsum

\end{document}
```

---

By default the first page of a `\chapter` is given `\thispagestyle{chapter}` (see [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), section **7.2 Page styles**) and the `chapter` page style is a copy - actually an *alias* - of `plain` (see section **7.3 Making headers and footers**).

You first have to fully create the `chapter` page style, either as a completely new style (via `\makepagestyle{chapter}`) or as a copy of some other style (like `\copypagestyle{chapter}`).

Then you can change the style to suit your needs:

```
\makepagestyle{chapter}% Officially create the chapter page style
\makeheadrule{chapter}{<width>}{<thickness>}% Header rule specification
\makefootrule{chapter}{<width>}{<thickness>}{<skip>}% Footer rule specification
\makeevenhead{chapter}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}% Even header
\makeoddhead {chapter}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}% Odd header
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}% Even footer
\makeoddfoot {chapter}{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}% Odd footer
```

Here is a complete minimal example highlighting the procedure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% This creates (and overrides) the chapter page style - set on the 
% first page of a \chapter
\makepagestyle{chapter}
\makeheadrule{chapter}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{chapter}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeoddhead {chapter}{left header}{chapter odd header}{right header}
\makeoddfoot {chapter}{left footer}{chapter odd footer}{right footer}
\makeevenhead{chapter}{left header}{chapter even header}{right header}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{left footer}{chapter even footer}{right footer}

% This is everything else - set on "chapter content" pages
\makepagestyle{alternate}
\makeheadrule{alternate}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{alternate}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}
\makeoddhead {alternate}{left header}{alternate odd header}{right header}
\makeoddfoot {alternate}{left footer}{alternate odd footer}{right footer}
\makeevenhead{alternate}{left header}{alternate even header}{right header}
\makeevenfoot{alternate}{left footer}{alternate even footer}{right footer}

\pagestyle{alternate}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\chapter{Non-Styled Chapter}
\chapterprecis{Ideally the only code would be the \texttt{\string\include} command.
  Authors will only have TeX code specific to their own content - with no knowledge of current styles, 
  \textit{etc.} There would be no ``\texttt{\string\pagestyle}'' commands in these \texttt{\string\include}-ed files.
  Here, chapter content pages have no custom headers and footers.}
\lipsum

\chapter{Test Chapter With required \texttt{\string\pagestyle} command}
\chapterprecis{Required to use inner Styling to get Headers and Footers.}
\lipsum

\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\chapter{Testing Bianchi Chapter Style}
\chapterprecis{Built in Chapter Styles have no impact on headers and footers.%
  Have to resort to including \texttt{\string\pagestyle} in order to override possible%
  corruption of default \texttt{\string\pagestyle\string{chapter\string}}}
\lipsum

\chapter{Non-Styled Chapter}
\chapterprecis{Chapter Without Any Style Commands. Inherits globally altered changes.
  This is what I am hoping to avoid.}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: @elikakohen: I added some more detail towards the end to show how you can have the `\tableofcontents` with a different style than the other `\chapter`s.

Comment: @elikakohen: You are confusing *chapter* styles with *page* styles, as far as I can tell. I've elaborated on this in the first part of my answer, as well as address your question about `\xpatchcmd`.

Comment: @elikakohen: The way you're using it - with `\makeoddhead`, `\makeoddfoot`, ... as part of `\makechapterstyle` - does make it seem like the header/footer forms part of the chapter style. However, your use is incorrect. Sure it works, but that is only because `\chapterstyle{ChapterHead}` calls whatever is stored inside the `ChapterHead` chapters style (actually `\chs@ChapterHead`). That doesn't mean you're using it correctly.

Comment: @Werner - I removed all references to Chapter Styles, to avoid this distraction.  Again, I only included it as a way to solve this problem, (which seems very non-standard).  I added your code example to mine - to show the issues with having to add style macros to every `\chapter`.

Comment: @elikakohen: I have to admit, your edits seem to make the problem more complex than is needed. If you want "to override all chapter title and content pagestyles", then simply issue `\chapterstyle` at the point from which you want them to apply (typically in the preamble or `\AtBeginDocument`) and redefine the `chapter` page style in the same way (in the preamble via `\makepagestyle{chapter} ...`).

Comment: @werner - I understand.  I am currently using \xpatchcmd to do it the simple way, and trying to avoid the complexity of repeating the same code everywhere.  Was just hoping Memoir had a way too.   If there is no way, (either in the Memoir or Book classes), then I would accept that as the answer. \o/  Even if Book has a way, that would be awesome.

Comment: @elikakohen: That's what I don't understand about your request anymore. My suggested solutions use `memoir`s techniques for setting both the page and chapter styles. I don't see any "repeated code" in my solution. I think I just don't understand your problem entirely.

Comment: @werner - I posted your code in my example.  You should be able to see that it doesn't quite work. Your code doesn't seem to set custom page styles differently for both Chapter Title and Content Pages.  Your code might not also apply to all chapters in the document, if someone uses other style tags, or even the `{plain}` or `{empty}` styles. It also doesn't seem to account for scenarios when the default `\chapter` style gets corrupted.  I tried to use all of those examples in the sample code, just to show some of the issues.

Comment: @elikakohen: Now that you've made it clear what you're referring to when you mention chapter *title* and *content* pages, the solution is straight forward. Just define the `chapter` page style - it'll affect all chapter *title* pages, and set the regular page style to `alternate` - it's affect all chapter *content* pages.